# SQL String array parameter for Like

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an MS SQL stored procedure to which I need to pass in a string array to for use with the LIKE operator. How am I best to achieve this, as there are no built in datatypes that I've come across to achieve this? I've seen implementations whereby a varchar is passed with a delimiter and logic in the SQL script splits this and dynamically builds up the statement.

None of these implementations really seem clean to me, how is this best achieved?

Thanks

```
DECLARE @ContractId int
DECLARE @QuantityPerVehicle decimal(18, 4)
DECLARE @OrderQuantity decimal(18, 4)
DECLARE @OrderDelivered decimal(18, 4)
DECLARE @Description varchar(200)

DECLARE @PendingUsage decimal(18, 4) = 0

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR select ContractId, QuantityPerVehicle, OrderQuantity, OrderDelivered, Description FROM prod.BillOfMaterialLineDetails where ([description] like '%line item 1%' OR [description] like '%line item 2%' OR [description] like '%line item 3%') and ContractId is not null
OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ContractId, @QuantityPerVehicle, @OrderQuantity, @OrderDelivered, @Description

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @JobsRemaining int
        SELECT @JobsRemaining = COUNT(JobId) FROM prod.JobDetails where JobStarted is null and ContractId = @ContractId
        SET @PendingUsage = @PendingUsage + (@JobsRemaining * @QuantityPerVehicle)

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ContractId, @QuantityPerVehicle, @OrderQuantity, @OrderDelivered, @Description
    END

CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor


select @PendingUsage as PendingUsage
```

Comment: You might want to read up on [Joins](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191517(v=sql.105).aspx). You shouldn't be writing cursors to select values from one table just to then be able to query another table multiple times for each matching value.

Answer (score 0):

This look's clean for me

```
SELECT contractid, 
       quantitypervehicle, 
       orderquantity, 
       orderdelivered, 
       description 
FROM   prod.billofmateriallinedetails B 
       JOIN (VALUES ('%line item 1%'), 
                    ('%line item 2%'), 
                    ('%line item 3%')) tc(line_item) 
         ON B.description LIKE tc.line_item 
WHERE  contractid IS NOT NULL
```